# Bottom Center in CSS (thumb tray)

Tags: jquery, html, css, helper

I have spent hours googleing on how to do this and have tried many different things. I cant get this Thumb Tray to center at the bottom of the page. Wanted to see if maybe someone can help me out. Here is the website. [www.Gabitee.com](http://www.GabiTee.com) and the code I have been messing with...

From file supersized.css

```
/* Thumbnail Tray
----------------------------*/          
#thumb-tray{ background:#fff; position:fixed; z-index:3; bottom:3px; right:0; background: transparent; padding-top: 8px; height:80px; width:100%; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; }

    #thumb-back, #thumb-forward{ position:absolute; z-index: 9999; bottom: -2px; height:108px; width: 40px; }
        #thumb-back{ left:0; background: transparent;}
        #thumb-forward{ right:0; background: transparent no-repeat center center;}
            #thumb-back:hover, #thumb-forward:hover{ cursor:pointer; background-color:rgba(256,256,256, 0.1); }
                #thumb-back:hover{ border-right:1px solid rgba(256,256,256, 0.2); }
                #thumb-forward:hover{ border-left:1px solid rgba(256,256,256, 0.2); }


    #thumb-tray{ display:inline-block; list-style:none; padding:0 0px; background: #fff; }
        ul#thumb-list li{ background:#fff;list-style:none; display:inline; overflow:hidden; float: left; }
            ul#thumb-list li img { opacity:0.6; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"; filter:alpha(opacity=60); margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px; width: 60px; height: 60px; }
            ul#thumb-list li.current-thumb img, ul#thumb-list li:hover img{ opacity:1; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
            ul#thumb-list li:hover{ cursor:pointer; }

            #tray-button { position: fixed; right: 50px; top: 20px; cursor: pointer; }
```

I was messing with the #thumb-tray{} at the top with firebug and textwrangler (osx)...I got it to move around but not the the bottom center... I have a background in JAVA but this to me is confusing.

This is my first time asking a question on here. I'm not sure if i am asking correctly.... lol sorry ... please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following styles will center the thumbs:

```
#thumb-list {
    text-align: center;     /* Centers the <li> */
    width: 100% !important; /* Overwrites the inline width */
}

ul#thumb-list li {
    display: inline-block;  /* Will get the <li> to wrap the <img> nicely */
    float: none;            /* Allows text-align: center on parent element to kick in */
}
```

**Edit:** This will also work:

```
#thumb-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```